# Diagrams to books

Tags: pgfplots, books

I am interested to write "Engineering Drawing book", but in which I have to give many diagrams with different types of lines and colors. If I use Latex book format,for the diagrams any one suggest cad packages giving output in pgf plot or any package allows to save  in Eps format or any other easy method.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! What is your specific latex related question? - Do you know [texample.net-Diagrams examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/) there you could find a lot of examples.

Comment: You may use Ti*k*Z and inkscape or, even better, write the latex code for your pictures yourself. There is no need to convert the pictures to eps. If compilation time is an issue, you can use externalize.

Comment: @marmot Inkscape will be suitable which directly saves as epf but time consuming. CAD packages does not allow to save in eps to get vector graphics on the book.

Comment: @velu your link doesn't work anymore. - Please add all relevant informations (like sample diagram) in your question above (use the edit button). At the moment your question is unclear and it sounds a bit like "Please do my work for me". If you would provide some [working code (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and and image (how it should look like at the end) you would help you and use.